# Activity Sharing with a Community User

Tags: community, partner-communities, activity-settings

We have an Opportunity owned by a Community User. A normal user creates activities under the Opportunity. However, the community User is unable to view these activities. The OWD for Activity is Controlled by Parent. As per Salesforce docs, (https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=activities_access.htm), the community user should be able to see the activity since it has access to the parent?

What am I missing here? Or does the activity sharing work differently for Community user?

[Edit: 14 May] I raised a case with salesforce on this and there response was that this is not possible. You cannot share the activity owned by an Internal user with an Community User even if the Community user is the owner of the record and sharing record is Controlled by Parent.

So my question is the above statement from Salesforce true? Have anyone ever shared activities owned by internal user with community user?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a standard field on Task/Event called **Public**, which is not visible by default, not even for System Administrators. The value of this checkbox needs to be `true` to make the event visible for external users in a community.

Comment: Can you provide a source for this? I haven't been able to find anything on it.

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=event_fields.htm

Comment: Thanks. That solved the problem. That was so obvious that I feel embarrassed now.

Answer (score 1):

The reference you've cited is for sharing within your primary SF Org, not within your Community. You'll need to set-up additional sharing for your community which might include enabling External Org Wide Defaults. Primary resources you'll want to look at are [Getting Started with Communities](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_communities_implementation.meta/salesforce_communities_implementation/), the [Security Workbook](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/workbook_security/workbook_security.pdf), the [Security Implementation Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/) and possibly [A Guide to Sharing Architecture](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dat.meta/dat/) as well.

**Edit**

With a partner community, everything is going to begin with how Accounts are shared since Opportunities and Contacts are both children of Accounts. You may need to revisit your sharing model from the ground up in order to achieve your desired results, both internally and externally.

The first thing I'd recommend you look at is whether the related activity is visible internal to Org when viewed from Opportunity. If it's not, then perhaps there's an issue with the WhatID on the Activity which could be the root cause of your problem. I don't know if you use Opportunity Teams or not, but that may be something you'll need to implement and then set-up sharing around those to allow Community Users who are on those Teams to see view everything related to their Accounts and Opportunities from the Community side of things. You may also need to look at Partner Profiles to see if they have all the necessary permissions enabled that are available to them. This is a many pronged approach to solving your problem.

In essence, you're going to need to study the materials I've referred you to in order to come up with a solution that works for your Org and Community. Its very difficult, if not impossible, for someone like me to give you an answer that will solve your problem without being able to look at your Org and see how everything is configured. The best I can do is point you in the direction of where you might want to look. Ultimately, I believe you're going to need to create sharing groups. You may find that what will work best for your org is to disable External Org Wide Defaults and only use Sharing Groups, which is how this was all done with Communities and Portals until fairly recently.

Comment: I couldn't find anything in the above doc about activities sharing with community.

Comment: The references are of a more general nature about how to share records from production orgs with Communities and set up security models for them in general. Each situation is unique and you'll need to sort out how best to share your Events with your Community members. In your case, with your current sharing model, how you share Opportunities will affect the sharing of Events. Again, look at enabling External Org Wide Defaults if you haven't already.

Comment: 1. External Sharing is enabled.
2. The Community user is Owner of the Opportunity.
3. What I meant was that I couldn't anything in the docs about the possibilities of sharing the activities of internal users with Community users especially when the community user has full access of the activity related record. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Internally, are you using the same OWD? If so, you'll likely need to create sharing groups in order to share the activities of your internal users with community users. I'm guessing that your community users can see the internal user's activity on the related activity list of Opportunity, but can't see the Activity detail page, correct? If that's the case, you'll want to create sharing groups & rules for Activities related to Opp.

Comment: In the sharing rules, I only see an option to define the OWD for Task and Activity but no Sharing Rules for them. Also, the community user can't see the Activities in the related list as well. I have a feeling that either this is not possible or I am missing something very simple in the setting. :(

Comment: See my edited response.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking your time out and providing a detailed response. I will get back here when I have solved this issue.

Comment: FYI. I raised a case with Salesforce and got an reply that this is not possible. My question has additional details on the response. Thank you.

Comment: Interesting response from SF. Seems like different behavior than what existed with Partner Portals, but I could be mistaken on that.